# Android Paging library - releasing cached data

Tags: android-paging, android-paging-library

I read a few resources on [Android Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/). While the topic sounds great, I'm unable to understand how and when the resources are released from DataSource in [DataSource+Network scenario](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/images/paging-library-data-flow.webp).

What if I have a very large list (lets say hundreds of MBs) and I need to keep the storage footprint low? Who and when will cleanup unused rows from underlying data source?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Nope. I put it off my mind back then, but I’m still very interested in the answer.

Comment: Hey. You can check out the accepted answer here. I hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858410/android-paging-library-sqlite-data-storage-concern